# A combination of winforms' controls as a prefab?

Tags: winforms

In our winforms application we often have a situation where the same panel is used in different forms. Right now I simply copy the code and the designer elements from form to form but that is obviously a terrible practice.

So I thought of making a class that could be easily added to a different form as a "component". The only problem is to be able to prototype and maintain this panel in the visual designer in such a way that if I want to change the panel's appearance in the future it gets changed for every class instance I created.

For instance I have a panel that provides search functionality:
[image]

Alongside with the code for click/textChanged events. I want to encapsulate it in a class, which I would be able to instantiate and initialize in any form's constructor to instantly add these controls (alongside events) into that form. Now it is not necessary for me to see the controls in the designer of the recepient form, however, I need to be able to see them in the designer somewhere in order to modify them if I would ever require that.

And if I do modify the appearance somehow (for instance add an extra button) these controls instantly change across the entire project, everywhere I instantiated the class.

I do know that all this can easily be done just creating a new form and encapsulating everything in it, I just wonder if it can be done for a group of controls instead.

Comment: just create a new UserControl and encapsulate everything in it

Comment: Right click your project -> go to "Add" and click on UserControl

Comment: Ok, looks like it was right under my nose :). If you would like to put it in an answer I would accept it. But please DO write about "Project->Add" and stuff :), cuz I do enjoy when answers on Stack are as streamlined and easy to digest as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just described the perfect use of a User Control. It's easy to use and direct.

First Add a user COntrol to the project:

[image]

Then add the desired controls on the user control:

[image]

Build the project and you will see the UserControl on the toolbox:

[image]

Add them to the form as a standard control:

[image]

If you change the code for the user control (in this case adding a button click handler) uit will affect all the intances of that user control:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = "Button Clicked"
End Sub
```

[image]

Note: If you have the Control in another project on the same solution, make sure you build that project too if you make any change.